# Postgres's column comment in Presto

Tags: postgresql, comments, presto

I am a newbie in Presto connected to PostgreSQL.
In my Postgre, I made a 'id' column with a comment '[pk][uk]' in Postgre and I got metadata using JDBC like below:

```
TABLE_CAT - null
TABLE_SCHEM - public
TABLE_NAME - department
COLUMN_NAME - id
DATA_TYPE - 1
TYPE_NAME - bpchar
COLUMN_SIZE - 10
...
REMARKS - [pk][uk]
```

But REMARKS has null in Presto when I print metadata using JDBC.

```
TABLE_CAT - okp
TABLE_SCHEM - public
TABLE_NAME - department
COLUMN_NAME - id
DATA_TYPE - 1
TYPE_NAME - char(10)
COLUMN_SIZE - 10
...
REMARKS - null
```

Question 1. Does not Presto support column's comment?

Question 2. If Presto support column's comment, how can I add a comment on column?

Presto's version is 0.235 and Postgre 13.

Answer (score 3):

1. Support for column comment in JDBC based connector (including PostgreSQL) was added in version [326](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/release/release-326.html). Could you upgrade your Presto version?
   https://prestosql.io/download.html
2. Setting column isn't yet supported in PostgreSQL connector. It's ongoing in this PR https://github.com/prestosql/presto/pull/5307.